# Scraping data from highchart in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, highcharts

would anyone be able to help with scraping the data from this chart using R?

https://www.solactive.com/indices/?index=DE000SLA3447

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I can see it, the relevant data is contained in the html that you find when inspecting the graph on firefox. If you click on copy outer html and put it in a reader you get a list of what I can only assume are the coordinates.

You should be able to retreive the relevant data using rvest and using some text extraction. Then of course you have to somehow transform it to the format you want.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this. I'm using Firefox but I don't see a "copy outer html" after right-clicking "Inspect Element (Q)".  Could you please provide a little more detail? thanks

Comment: right click  and inspect element --> right click on the part of the code --> copy --> outer html